# What kind of standoffs are used when attaching expanded metal concrete-reinforcing mesh

Tags: concrete, fastener, expanded-mesh

Are there special-purpose standoffs made for securing expanded mesh to concrete? I want to fashion an extruded L-shape using expanded metal mesh in order to repair a crumbing concrete edge and hope to attach the mesh securely to the concrete.

Comment: I don’t think I would use stand-offs I would probably drill holes and use tapcons with the metal inside a form for strength depending on the thickness I might use construction cloth as it is easier to form and it makes a great reenforcement.

Comment: @EdBeal  Use the head of the tapcon to hold the square-mesh an inch or so from the surface of the old concrete?